# Error de expresión: objeto con nombre: omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter no encontrado

Tags: java, jsf

Me encuentro utilizando esta función de OmniFaces llamada SelectItemsConverter, pero me ocurre este error cuando entro al .xhtml que lo implementa:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{productoBean.producto.tipo_producto}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" >
   <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Seleccione" itemValue="#{null}" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{tipoProductoBean.listaTipoProductos}" var="tipoProduc" itemLabel="#{tipoProduc.nombre_tipo_producto}" itemValue="#{tipoProduc}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Este es el Stack Trace:

> javax.faces.FacesException: Error de expresión: objeto con nombre: omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter no encontrado.
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:1341)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValueHolderRule$LiteralConverterMetadata.applyMetadata(ValueHolderRule.java:85)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:473)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:206)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:990)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

El modelo ya tiene implementados los métodos de:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 31 * hash + this.tipo_producto_id;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final TipoProducto other = (TipoProducto) obj;
    if (this.tipo_producto_id != other.tipo_producto_id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s[tipo_producto_id=%d]", getClass().getSimpleName(), getTipo_producto_id());
}
```

Quien pueda ayudarme a solucionar este error, le agradecería mucho.

Comment: ¿Has agregado la librería en el xhtml? ¿Y porque tienes componentes de PrimeFaces? ¿O no es PrimeFaces el componente <p:selectOneMenu...?

Comment: Tengo dos situaciones: la primera es que cuando agrego la libreria al xhtml y al proyecto, me sale esto:

`D:\Workspace\NetBeansProjects\Bodegas\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1054: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.`
Y no me levanta el proyecto. La otra situacion es que no le agrego esto y me levanta el proyecto, pero cuando abro el xhtml que implementa este SelectItemsConverter me muestra este error.

`Error de expresión: objeto con nombre: omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter no encontrado`

Comment: ¿Y para qué necesitas ese converter de OmniFaces?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que yo estoy realizando un proyecto JSF con primefaces, pero vi que esta librería de Omnifaces me ayuda para la funcionalidad de asociar un objeto con otro objeto. Es decir en el selectOneMenu me carga una lista de objetos y necesito llevar ese objeto al value. Si me hago entender?

Comment: Es una pregunta un poco básica, pero para asegurarnos... ¿tienes el `jar` de omnifaces en el `WEB-INF/lib` del `war`?

Comment: Si, tengo este .jar ( OmniFaces 2.5.1) file. Uso netbeans, se encuentra agregado a las librerias del proyecto.

Comment: ¿Has añadido xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar un converter genérico para las entidades. En mis proyectos utilizo este converter:

```
/**
 * Converter para entidades JPA. Baseia-se nas anotações @Id e @EmbeddedId para
 * identificar o atributo que representa a identidade da entidade. Capaz de
 * detectar as anotações nas classes superiores.
 *
 * @author Flávio Henrique
 * @version 1.0.3
 * @since 05/10/2010
 */

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@FacesConverter("entityConverter")
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value != null) {
        return component.getAttributes().get(value);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && !"".equals(obj)) {
        String id;
        try {
            id = this.getId(getClazz(ctx, component), obj);
            if (id == null) {
                id = "";
            }
            id = id.trim();
            component.getAttributes().put(id, getClazz(ctx, component).cast(obj));
            return id;
        } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // seu log aqui
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Obtém, via expression language, a classe do objeto.
 *
 * @param FacesContext facesContext
 * @param UICompoment compoment
 * @return Class<?>
 */
private Class<?> getClazz(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component) {
    return component.getValueExpression("value").getType(facesContext.getELContext());
}

/**
 * Retorna a representação em String do retorno do método anotado com @Id ou
 *
 * @param obj
 * @throws java.lang.NoSuchFieldException
 * @throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException
 * @EmbeddedId do objeto.
 * @param clazz<?> clazz
 * @return String
 */
public String getId(Class<?> clazz, Object obj) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    List<Class<?>> hierarquiaDeClasses = this.getHierarquiaDeClasses(clazz);

    for (Class<?> classeDaHierarquia : hierarquiaDeClasses) {
        for (Field field : classeDaHierarquia.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if ((field.getAnnotation(Id.class)) != null || field.getAnnotation(EmbeddedId.class) != null) {
                Field privateField = classeDaHierarquia.getDeclaredField(field.getName());
                privateField.setAccessible(true);
                if (privateField.get(clazz.cast(obj)) != null) {
                    return (String) field.getType().cast(privateField.get(clazz.cast(obj))).toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Retorna uma lista com a hierarquia de classes, sem considerar a classe
 * Object.class
 *
 * @param clazz
 *
 * @return List<Class<?>> clazz
 */
public List<Class<?>> getHierarquiaDeClasses(Class<?> clazz) {

    List<Class<?>> hierarquiaDeClasses = new ArrayList<>();
    Class<?> classeNaHierarquia = clazz;
    while (classeNaHierarquia != Object.class) {
        hierarquiaDeClasses.add(classeNaHierarquia);
        classeNaHierarquia = classeNaHierarquia.getSuperclass();

    }
    return hierarquiaDeClasses;
}
```

}

Como puedes ver, esta clase no es de mi autoría, no recuerdo de dónde la copié; pero allí van los créditos.

Luego en tu `selectOneMenu` sería algo así:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{productoBean.producto.tipo_producto}" converter="entityConverter" >
   <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Seleccione" itemValue="#{null}" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{tipoProductoBean.listaTipoProductos}" var="tipoProduc" itemLabel="#{tipoProduc.nombre_tipo_producto}" itemValue="#{tipoProduc}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

No habrá necesidad de agregar la librería de OmniFaces, quédate solo con PrimeFaces.

La ventaja es que este converter te funciona para diferentes componentes, yo lo utilizo casi en todos, únicamente cuando el convertidor necesite hacer otras validaciones utilizo un converter diferente.

Saludos.

Comment: Ahh perfecto, lo probaré y te digo que tal me fue con esta solución. Muchas gracias por su colaboración